# android download Bitmap from url ran into out of memory exception

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-asynctask, bitmapfactory

I`m building some app that loads images from url and when the user scroll down the app download more images.

after about 30 downloads I get out of memory exception.  I read about it here and in android developer but I could not find a way to make it run.

this is my code for download image:

```
for (int k = 0; k < pictureAry.length(); k++) {
                    try {
                        URL url = new URL(picUrl + pictureAry.getString(k)
                                + "/230");
                        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                                .openConnection();
                        connection.setDoInput(true);
                        connection.connect();
                        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                        picArrayList.add(myBitmap);
                        break;

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                                context.getResources(),
                                R.drawable.icon_0404);
                        picArrayList.add(myBitmap);
                    }
                }
```

and this one for display:

```
enter codeint bwidth = picArrayList.get(0).getWidth();
                int bheight = picArrayList.get(0).getHeight();
                int swidth = mainTableForAllPosts.getWidth();
                int sheight = mainTableForAllPosts.getHeight();
                int new_width = swidth;
                int new_height = (int) Math.floor((double) bheight
                        * ((double) new_width / (double) bwidth));                  
                newbitMap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
                        picArrayList.get(0), new_width, new_height, true);
                mainImageView.setImageBitmap(newbitMap);

            } else
                mainImageView
                        .setImageBitmap(overlay(bitmapForVideoThumbnails));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            mainImageView.setImageResource(com.gy.bll.R.drawable.icon_0404);

        }
```

its not writing here but I try to use bitmapFactory.options but I got stack probably because my source is Url and not file.

this is the log cat:

> 06-27 12:30:10.008: E/dalvikvm(11265): Out of memory: Heap Size=98304KB, Allocated=92688KB, Limit=98304KB, Proc Limit=98304KB
>   06-27 12:30:10.008: E/dalvikvm(11265): Extra info: Footprint=97504KB, Allowed Footprint=98304KB, Trimmed=1588KB
>   06-27 12:30:10.013: E/Bitmap_JNI(11265): Create Bitmap Failed.
>   06-27 12:30:10.013: E/Bitmap_JNI(11265): Failed to create SkBitmap!
>   06-27 12:30:10.013: W/dalvikvm(11265): threadid=16: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41991a08)
>   06-27 12:30:10.013: E/AndroidRuntime(11265): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
>   06-27 12:30:10.013: E/AndroidRuntime(11265): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>   06-27 12:30:10.013: E/AndroidRuntime(11265):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
>   06-27 12:30:10.013: E/AndroidRuntime(11265):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
>   06-27 12:30:10.013: E/AndroidRuntime(11265):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
>   06-27 12:30:10.013: E/AndroidRuntime(11265):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
>   06-27 12:30:10.013: E/AndroidRuntime(11265):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
>   06-27 12:30:10.013: E/AndroidRuntime(11265):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
>   06-27 12:30:10.013: E/AndroidRuntime(11265):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
>   06-27 12:30:10.013: E/AndroidRuntime(11265):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
>   06-27 12:30:10.013: E/AndroidRuntime(11265): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: (Heap Size=98304KB, Allocated=92688KB)
>   06-27 12:30:10.013: E/AndroidRuntime(11265):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreateScaledBitmap(Native Method)
>   06-27 12:30:10.013: E/AndroidRuntime(11265):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:809)
>   06-27 12:30:10.013: E/AndroidRuntime(11265):    at com.gy.bll.JsonParser.makeGuiRow(JsonParser.java:516)
>   06-27 12:30:10.013: E/AndroidRuntime(11265):    at com.gy.bll.JsonParser.access$1(JsonParser.java:332)
>   06-27 12:30:10.013: E/AndroidRuntime(11265):    at com.gy.bll.JsonParser$jsonPostAsyncTask.doInBackground(JsonParser.java:299)
>   06-27 12:30:10.013: E/AndroidRuntime(11265):    at com.gy.bll.JsonParser$jsonPostAsyncTask.doInBackground(JsonParser.java:1)
>   06-27 12:30:10.013: E/AndroidRuntime(11265):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
>   06-27 12:30:10.013: E/AndroidRuntime(11265):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
>   06-27 12:30:10.013: E/AndroidRuntime(11265):    ... 4 more

for now Im using android:largeHeap="true" in my manifest its make my app dont crash but I see in the log that the heep grwos to 250m + and its make my app run slow.

thanks.

Comment: Please post he logcat also in a code block as now the lines wrap and make it unreadable. Further it is a bad idea to put all bitmaps in a list. In this way you need a lot of memory and your memory runs out. Much better to save them to file first. Do not use BitmapFactory for that either as it will put the whole file in memory first. Just use your own inputstream/fileoutputstream and read/write a buffer in a loop. If you need to use bitmaps in for instance a getView() load them from file. You can then resize them if needed.

Comment: I clear the list every loop so I have only 1-3 images per loop.   I dont know how to make this inputstream/fileoutputstream youve said.. can you give my an example please?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use image scaling mechanism.
2. Don't try to download every time. If once its downloaded then store into cache memory.

Comment: 1. how do I use this mechanism? whats the different from this to Bitmap.createScaledBitmap?                                           2.what do you mean? I have many different images I have to download every time.. my problem that I use to many cache memory so I dont think this is the solution...

Comment: For the 1., I don't think you can scale the image while downloading, maybe possible with some interleaved formats as a hack, but not generally. For 2) I think you meant filesystem instead of memory.

Comment: @GiliYaniv  Presntly ur  holding all the bitmap object in arraylist. Instead of that of you have to store that bitmap objects.

Comment: as ive said.. i clear rhe arraylist every loop.. how do you sugeat i transfer the bit map to other method?